# CSS @document Safari Alternative (site specific CSS override in a custom style sheet)

Tags: css, safari

I am using a custom style sheet in Safari that applies globally, but I want to exclude one specific website from that style.

I tried @document domain(example.com) { css rule }, but I don't think the @document is supported by Safari (see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html)
(I also tried several other including @-moz-document or variantions like url(), url-prefix()...)

Is there an alternative way to exclude specific sites from a custom css style sheet in Safari?

Best